# Need clarity in Understanding liskov substitution principle

Tags: python, oop, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

LSP definition states that,If S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T in a program may be replaced with objects of type S without altering any of the desirable properties of that program.

1. Preconditions cannot be strengthened in a subtype
2. Postconditions cannot be weakened in a subtype.
3. Invariants of the supertype must be preserved in a subtype.

For example, I have below classes
Is this a violation of( Preconditions cannot be strengthened in a subtype).
I am trying to wrap my head around this ,Can someone please provide a good example to understand it.

```
Class Switch:
   def __init__(self,ip,dc):
       self.ip=ip
       self.dc=dc

class CiscoSwitch(Switch):
   def __init__(self,ip,dc,zone):
       super().__init__(ip,dc)
       self.zone=zone

class JuniperSwitch(Switch):
   def __init__(self,ip,dc,zone):
       super().__init__(ip,dc)
       self.zone=zone
```

Comment: You haven't defined any preconditions(?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LSP principle works through interfaces, that is, what is public in the object/value. In the case of Python, you have attributes and methods that are public and therefore, if you are implementing an interface you must adhere to it.
In your example, the `Switch` class defines an interface only regarding its attributes, that is, it has the `ip` and `dc` fields. Since you are calling `super` in `CiscoSwitch` and `JuniperSwitch`, they both have those fields, and therefore implement the "interface" of  `Switch` and they may replace it.

Now, let's tackle the conditions you mentioned:

1. Preconditions cannot be strengthened in a subtype

Suppose you have an interface with a method that colors a shape and this method accepts only hexadecimal colors (`"#123456"`) or rgb colors (`(123,124,125)`). Suppose you create a class Rectangle that implements this interface, but it accepts only rgb colors. You're strengthening the pre-condition. If you have this line in your code:
`generic_shape.color("#123456")`

You cannot replace your Rectangle in it, so you are breaking LSP.

2. Postconditions cannot be weakened in the subtype

A classical example would be returning `None` for a method that should not return `None`. Suppose that in the Shape interface, you have a `getSide` method, and you create a `Circle` class, and when implementing this method, you return `None`. This breaks the caller expectative and may cause an unexpected error:

```
side = generic_shape.get_side() # suppose it is a circle
scaled_side = side * 2 # you get an error
```

3. Invariants of the supertype must be preserved in a subtype

This one is more complex in my opinion, because it is hard to make it explicit. The only example I can think is keeping a property non-Null, suppose in your example you have a Switch that doesn't use IP (maybe uses MAC-addr), if the Switch interface expects that the `ip` field should not be None, your MAC-Switch will be broking this interface.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Would you consider the extra parameter in the subclass `__init__` signatures to be a violation?

Comment: @snakecharmerb The constructor is not part of the contract so no.

Comment: Thanks for the simple exaplanation ,I feel like 3rd rule is still foggy to me but this is good enough